# Error psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict' from PokeJSON

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

Can't insert into SQL table the first 100 Pokemon from PokeApi

```
import psycopg2
import json
import myutils
import requests
conn=psycopg2.connect(                                                                                                                          
    host='host',database='database',
    user='user',password='password',
    connect_timeout=3)
cur=conn.cursor()
sql='DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pokeapi;'
cur.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
print(sql)
sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pokeapi (id SERIAL,body JSONB);'
cur.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
print(sql)   
for i in range(1,101):
    url='https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/%s' % (str(i))                                                                                       
    response = requests.get(url)
    text = response.text
    js = json.loads(text)
    stuff = js.get('forms', None)
    sql='INSERT INTO pokeapi VALUES (%s)'
    cur.execute(sql,(stuff,))
    conn.commit()
    print(sql)
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'
```

Notice the JSON structure

```
"species":{"name":"bulbasaur","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/1/"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must [adapt the python dict to Json](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation) when passing it as a query parameter.

```py
from psycopg2.extras import Json

#...
cur.execute(sql,(Json(stuff),))
```

Comment: Changed as you requested it, the library retrieves successfully but the SQL table rejects it "INSERT INTO pokeapi VALUES ('[{"name": "bulbasaur", "url": "...  "

Comment: @DavideDunneSánchez. This:  `sql='INSERT INTO pokeapi VALUES (%s)'` is not going work as the `Json(stuff)` is going to be inserted into the `id` field. You need: `sql='INSERT INTO pokeapi(body) VALUES (%s)'`. Also when you post an error actually post the entire error message, that is basic troubleshooting.